# SQL datareader into int

Tags: c#, sql

I am simply trying to use a datareader to read the integer at datareader[0] into an integer called "price per night".

```
int price_per_night = 0;
while (read_price.Read())
{
    price_per_night = (read_price[0]);
}
```

No matter how many approaches I try it will not convert. Is there a definitive answer?

Comment: `int.Parse()`, `int.TryParse()`, `Convert.ToInt32()`, etc.

Comment: Try int.tryparse.. also what is the value of the "read_price[0]" , have you tried tostring() then parse as int?  Right now all I see is you taking what is an unknown type and trying to cram it into an int.

Comment: Now would also be a good time to read up on .NET naming conventions.

Comment: the value of "read_price" is 66.

Comment: What abut `read_price.GetInt32[0]`?  Don't forget to check for null `read_price.IsDBNull(0)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GetInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the reader and call is [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for a null value before calling this method.

Keep the following in mind on GetInt32:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must
>   already be a 32-bit signed integer.

```
int price_per_night = 0;
while (read_price.Read())
{
    if (!read_price.IsDBNull(0))
    {
       price_per_night = read_price.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

what about this?

```
price_per_night = Convert.ToInt32(read_price[0]);
```

Comment: doesnt work. "Input string is not in the correct format". I feel this should be simple but it seems quite the opposite.

Comment: Note that if `read_price[0]` is null or not a number it will throw an exception.